# Scala - double HashMap with MultiMap

Tags: scala, hash, hashtable, nested

I currently have a variable that looks like this:

```
val someVal = new HashMap[Float, Set[String]] with MultiMap[Float, String]
```

Now I would like to have a hash of these hashes of the form:

```
val someHashOfSomeVal = new HashMap[String, HashMap[Float, Set[String]] with MultiMap[Float, String]]
```

In other words, I need to have a hash table (with multiple values for each key) of hash tables (with multiple values of each key).  Can anyone help me with how I declare / mutate this variable?

Do I mutate it like this?`someHashOfSomeVal.addBinding("someKey", someVal)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear to me why you'd want the top-level map to have multiple values (other maps, in this case) per key, or how that would work in practice. I'll assume that you only want `MultiMap` at the lower level, in which case you can use the following approach:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{ HashMap, MultiMap, Set }    

class TwoLevel[A, B, C] extends HashMap[A, MultiMap[B, C]] {
  override def default(key: A) = new HashMap[B, Set[C]] with MultiMap[B, C]
  def addTriple(a: A, b: B, c: C) {
    this += a -> this(a).addBinding(b, c)
  }

  def lookupPair(a: A, b: B): Set[C] = this(a).getOrElse(b, Set.empty)
}

val m = new TwoLevel[String, Float, String]

m.addTriple("a", 1.0F, "b")
m.addTriple("a", 0.0F, "c")

println(m.lookupPair("a", 0.0F))
```

Which prints `Set(c)`, as you'd expect.